# Collecting a list of documents from a factory for an AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, array, functional-programming, angular.js

With this controller I'm injecting `myFactory` and using `Array.push()` to add the array `response.documents` to the `this.documents` array. I can't help feeling there's a better way without having to use `_this`.

```
function myController($route, myFactory) {
  'ngInject';

  this.$onInit = function() {
    const _this = this;
    const id = $route.current.params.someId;

    this.documents = [];

    myFactory.getData(id).then((response) => {

      console.log(response); // { "something": { "Id":1234 }, "documents":[{ "DocumentId":"2345", "DocumentName":"doc.docx" }] }
      console.log(response.documents); // [{ "DocumentId":"2345", "DocumentName":"doc.docx" }]

      response.documents.forEach((object) => {
        _this.documents.push(object);
      });
    });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Specify `this` context

I support [Blindman67's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/188194/120114). If arrow functions were not supported by all browsers used (e.g. [IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility) - but then again there is little support for Angular in IE anyway) then you could also utilize [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
this.$onInit = function() {
    const id = $route.current.params.someId;

    this.documents = [];

    myFactory.getData(id).then((response) => {
        response.documents.forEach((object) => {
            this.documents.push(object);
        }.bind(this));
    }
}
```

Or utilize the second parameter of [Array.foreach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (i.e. [**`thisArg`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Parameters)):

```
this.$onInit = function() {
    const id = $route.current.params.someId;

    this.documents = [];

    myFactory.getData(id).then((response) => {
        response.documents.forEach((object) => {
            this.documents.push(object);
          }, this);
    }
}
```

### Avoid the looping

Even simpler would be to push all items with the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), since [Array.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) can accept a variable number of elements:

```
this.$onInit = function() {
    const id = $route.current.params.someId;

    this.documents = [];

    myFactory.getData(id).then(response => this.documents.push(...response.documents));
}
```

Because `...response.documents` will spread the arguments out to match the [parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Syntax) (i.e. `element1[, ...[, elementN]]`).

That way there is no need to iterate over the items. [Array.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) could also be used but then the array would need to be re-assigned. Or [Array.unshift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) could also be used with the spread operator.

Expand the snippet below for a demonstration (AngularJS code removed for simplicity).

```js
const documents = [];
const id = 3;
const myFactory = {
  getData: function(id) {
    const newDocuments = [1,2,3];
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(resolve, 750, {"documents": newDocuments});
    });
  }
};
console.log('original documents',documents);
myFactory.getData(id).then(function(response) {
  documents.push(...response.documents);
  console.log('documents after push',documents);
})
```

Comment: Very nice, I think it's only fair to update this as the accepted answer. The different examples and explanation for each helped me more than an hours searching and reading could. I'm going with the snippet you provided and the spread operator. Thanks Sam.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Blindman said, I would recommend avoiding using `this` in nested scopes , which is always confusing and error prone, by assigning `documents` to a local variable. i.e.

```
this.$onInit = function() {
  const id = $route.current.params.someId;
  let documents =this.documents = [];
  ...
  response.documents.forEach((object) => {
    documents.push(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are not bound to `this` so your code can use `this`.

```
this.$onInit = function() {
  const id = $route.current.params.someId;    
  this.documents = [];

  myFactory.getData(id).then((response) => {  // Arrow function
    response.documents.forEach((object) => {  // Arrow function

      this.documents.push(object);   // <<===== use this not _this

    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Ah of course, sometimes I can't see the wood for the trees! Thanks!